# Work with image data returned from readAsDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there a way to manipulate (work with) image data that comes out of HTML5 FileReader function readAsDataUrl() ?

What I am interested in, is to load image and display only part of it. I can just cut the data string and it works, but I get error in console that image has been truncated.

I guess I will have to know the data structure. I would imagine that there will be header and the image data, just dont know how to calculate what is what and then calculate pixels in the image data.

Is it at all possible? Should I use canvas rather than trying to do it just in JS?

Comment: Canvas would be the easiest/most natural approach.

Comment: @Shomz I'm getting convinced. Is there a way to work with the image in canvas and then whatever is visible on canvas convert back to the data string?

Comment: @Tom -  You can use the dataURL as the `src` attribute of an `img` element. Once it has loaded, you can draw any/all of it to a canvas at the same size, or scaled. Once this is done, you can then get the dataURL from the canvas. I use just this technique to allow users to upload pictures of text, which I then automatically deskew (rotate) to ensure the page is straight, before allowing the user to crop unwanted areas and finally, to get a copy of the edited image back. All this works entirely on the client-side and without the use of a server of any kind.

Comment: @Tom, yes, absolutely. I've added three examples to my answer, showing stuff like resizing, cropping (this is probably what you want) and pixel modification. It should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @Shomz Great, I accepted your answer. Will dig in to the code. Actually what I need is not exactly cropping, more like splitting the image into differently shaped pieces

Comment: Then you should definitely go with the canvas. However, don't forget that in the end, all images are rectangular, so if you plan to do something like tangrams, you'll need to use transparency to fake the non-rectangular effect. I'm afraid I can't help you more unless you describe what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Shomz DOn't relayy want to shout out what Im doing over here for various reasons, but yes, I am going to add either solid color or transparent areas to the image so I preserve the rectangular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, canvas is probably the easiest and the most natural way to do it.

### EXAMPLE 1: Resizing

Here's a simple example of modifying an image using the canvas, and then building a modified image as HTML `img` element:

```js
function init() {
  var img = document.getElementById('orig');
  var mod = document.getElementById('mod');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 64;
  context.drawImage(img, 0,0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 64, 64);
  
  mod.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  
}
```

```html
<p>Original Image</p>
<img id="orig" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kUKEPU5ZpLw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABI/oVLnH7VD59A/photo.jpg" onload="init()" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
<p>Canvas Image</p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p>Modified Image</p>
<img id="mod" src="" />
```

This only resizes the image, but you can do anything you like, even on the pixel-level.

---

### EXAMPLE 2: Cropping

Here's another example of cropping the image:

```js
function init() {
  var img = document.getElementById('orig');
  var mod = document.getElementById('mod');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 64;
  context.drawImage(img, 64,64, 64, 64, 0, 0, 64, 64);
  
  mod.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  
}
```

```html
<p>Original Image</p>
<img id="orig" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kUKEPU5ZpLw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABI/oVLnH7VD59A/photo.jpg" onload="init()" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
<p>Canvas Image</p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p>Modified Image</p>
<img id="mod" src="" />
```

---

### EXAMPLE 3: Pixel-level modification

Let's kill off the reds:

```js
function init() {
  var img = document.getElementById('orig');
  var mod = document.getElementById('mod');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = canvas.height = 64;
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 64, 64);

  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
  var data = imageData.data;

  for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    data[i] = 0;
  }
  
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

  mod.src = canvas.toDataURL();

}
```

```html
<p>Original Image</p>
<img id="orig" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kUKEPU5ZpLw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABI/oVLnH7VD59A/photo.jpg" onload="init()" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
<p>Canvas Image</p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p>Modified Image</p>
<img id="mod" src="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw image into canvas, make anything you want with image pixels, do any other drawing operations and put the result into the DOM image object.

```
// get canvas context
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// draw image into canvas
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// get image data object
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

// get the pixels
var data = imageData.data;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    // manipulate image pixels
}

// put the pixels back onto canvas
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

// put canvas into image
img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Read the following articles for the detailed explanations and sample code:

[Mastering images with HTML5 canvas – part 1](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/mastering-images-html5-canvas-1) (Canvas image basics, grayscale and photo filters)

[Mastering images with HTML5 canvas – part 2](http://www.web-plus-plus.com/Articles/mastering-images-html5-canvas-2) (Clipping, transparency and brightness effects)